# How to change int value using function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to change int value using C# function added to onClick in button.
But if I have in Start() count_points = 3 that script not works properly.

```
public void AddPoint()
{
    count_points = count_points + 1;
    SetPointsText ();   
}
```

If I clicked on button which has onClick function AddPoint() changes only displayed text from Point 3 to Point 4, but this point it not counted.

```
public Text livesText;
    private int count_points;
```

And in Start():

```
count_lives = 3;
SetPointsText ();
```

Comment: Should work if the variable is properly defined.. How is the `count_points` being defined? As as a `public int` in this `MonoBehaviour` script, or is it a `static int`? How do you know that the point "didn't count"? We need more code.

Comment: I added more code to question.

Comment: Still open question: How do you know that "but this point it not counted", although it displays properly? Also, you can declare the starting value of `3` in the variable declaration `private int conut_points = 3;`.

Comment: I displaying it. When I click the button showing numbers change to 4 but i have still 3 points  because when my obcject colid with another collider that points change automatic from 4 to 2.

if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Meteor")) {

   other.gameObject.SetActive (false);
   count_points = count_points - 1;
   SetPointsText ();
  }

Comment: Add logging to it. Every time you add a point, log the value before and after the increase, and every time you decrease the value, do the same. That will you exactly how many points you had before and after an action took place. Maybe the collision happens twice, very rapidly, and decreases 2 points at once? Show us an action log.

Comment: Not the answer, but a good practice is to use variable += 1 instead of variable = variable + 1

Comment: but it works fine only it I add it to void Update

Comment: @MichałMasłoń Yes i know your solution works just fine. But generally it's just better practice :)

Comment: The additional code you included adds a bit more confusion for me - was `count_lives = 3;` a typo, or are you incorrectly associating `count_lives` and `count_points`? Are you accidentally checking `count_lives` (which isn't changing) rather than `count_points` (which may be changing)?

Comment: My fail. I didn't change lives to points before adding questions. But it is about the same.